# belongsTo not going to the right table

Tags: laravel

I have a controller with a function:

```
public function show(Activity $linkActivity, $id)
    {
        $activity = $this->activityRepository->getById($id);
        $project = $linkActivity::find($activity->project_id)->project;
        $employee = $linkActivity::find($activity->employee_id)->employee;
        //\Debugbar::info($manager);

        return view('activity/show',  compact('activity'))->with('project',$project)->with('employee',$employee);
    }
```

and here is my model Activity.php:

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

The problem is that it is not looking at the right table and it is calling the activity table instead of the employee table. In the debugbar, I see the request to the db done which is:

```
select * from `activity` where `activity`.`id` = '2' limit 1
```

And id is well the 2 from the employee I m asking it but it looks in the wrong table.
Why is that?

Comment: Your schema looks...confusing.  What the heck is `linkActivity` and why do you have to query that to find the employee when you already have the employee id?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a row in Activity with Employee ID? I'm not sure what exactly you want, but if you want an employee why not simply do this

```
 $employee = $activity->employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is in find($activity->project_id).

In fact in the find, I need to put the id of the record holding the foreign key and not the id of the foreign key itself.